# Border-Box 100% Width Calculation - Text Doesn't Fit

Tags: html, css, forms, button, width

I have an interesting box-model/width/inheritance problem I'm puzzling through. Basically, here's what I have:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div><input type="text">So the td is at least this big</input></div>
      <div>
        <button>The Fish Molecular Genetics and Biotechnology Laboratory</button>
        <button>Each button must be as wide as the widest one</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

In this simplified model, `<td>` has (and must have) auto width, `<button>` has 100% width and `display:block;` so that all buttons will be the same width, `<button>` also has some padding, and pretty much everything has `box-sizing:border-box;`.

So, when a button is rendered, its box width gets set to the width of the text it contains. But oh wait, its box width is measured from border to border and it has a padding, so the text actually wraps to the next line. And it has to be border-box because of many good reasons that are not apparent in the above simplified model. And the td has to have auto width because the buttons change in real time based on what's in the text box.

Comment: If I give the buttons a width of 102% it works, except that they are 2% wider than things that they're supposed to have the same width as, and it could perform inconsistently on small devices or if there's a bigger font size specified in a user-agent stylesheet.

Comment: Something like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/bw8XC/

Comment: @Shmiddty: At some point, I'm going to want to put a max-width on the td and have the really long ones wrap as usual. Replace `white-space:nowrap` with `padding:1em` to see the issue.

Comment: Is it necessary that they are buttons? You could use a div or an anchor tag instead.

Comment: It's not particularly necessary. I wonder if it would work differently, but not enough to go back now.

Comment: If you go with anchor tags, the box-sizing will work as it should. Buttons have always been a hassle to style because browsers won't give up full control of them.

Comment: Actually, anchor tags behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent fix, but I still think this qualifies as a bug.

```
<div>
  <button><span>The Fish Molecular Genetics and Biotechnology Laboratory</span></button>
  <button><span>Each button must be as wide as the widest one</span></button>
</div>
```

with

```css
button {padding:0;}
button span {margin:1em;}
```

---

**EDIT**
There's more than one thing going on here. A second problem was the ems. Apparently text wrapping can go awry when the text's container's width is rendered as 328.00003654 px. Switching to pixel units for the `span {margin:` fixed that.

Comment: Taking a look rapidly I have noted that you are using a tag name `<buttom>`. I never see it, is it a valid html tag?

Comment: Yes. I use them wherever I can for things that trigger an action as opposed to things that take you to another page or another place on the page. It avoids semantically pointless code like `<a href="#">` or `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`. The only downside is you have to style a ton in order for it not to render like an `<input type="button"/>`.